# Set the color of a UITableViews section title

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a number of sections. The are defaulted to the blue color, I would like to change it to another color.

How does one do this? I can only see where to set the name of the title for the section, but not the color.

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413436/change-uitable-section-backgroundcolor-without-loosing-section-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide a custom header view for each section with `– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`
 on the table view delegate.