# Make UIView scroll with UITableView but pin to top out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, scrollview

I currently have a `view controller` that is comprised of a `Navigation bar`, followed by a `UIView` that has two `UIButtons` added as subViews. There is then a `UITableView` underneath that begins at the bottom of the container `UIView`.

At the moment, when the user scrolls the `UITableView` it goes behind the `UIView` and `UIButtons`. What I actually want to happen is for the `UIView` and `UIButtons` to move up with the table view but only by the value of their height which in this case is 58 pixels. The flow would be like this...

1) Table scrolls and the `UIView` moves with it for the first 58 pixels.

2) The user continues to scroll the table but the `UIView` "pins" itself just out of view under the `navigation bar`.

3) When the user scrolls the table back down the `UIView` is then picked up and dragged back into view. I believe the new Facebook app does something similar in the timeline.

I don't want to set the `UIView` as the `TableHeaderView` of the table as I also have a pull-to-refresh which then sits above the buttons and looks terrible. I've tried playing around with the `contentOffset` properties of the underlying `scrollview` of the table but have hit a brick wall.

Any advice on where to start would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I am gotten a little further and using this code to move the frame of the UIView.

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog (@"Content Offset: %f", self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog (@"Button Frame: %f", self.btnBackground.frame.origin.y);

        if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0)
        {
            CGRect newFrame = self.btnBackground.frame;
            newFrame.origin.x = 0;
            newFrame.origin.y = -self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
            [self.btnBackground setFrame: newFrame];
        }  

}
```

The problem now is that the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method doesn't get fired quickly enough if the table view is scrolled fast. The result is that the UIView doesn't quite make all way back to its original position when scroll quickly.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to tackle a similar  issue right now. Did you ever figure out what to do? @paulmorris

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374090/move-a-view-when-scrolling-in-uitableview

Comment: Hey, me too came to a similar situation. The designer want the layout to behave exactly like CoordinatorLayout in Android. Btw did you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

The scroll content offset is a good idea.  Also if you tableview has only one section one approach is to do a custom header view representing the top level widgets.  If there is more than one sections create an additional empty section which would return your custom header.

You can refer to this stack overflow post.
[Customize UITableview Header Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)

Answer (score 0):

Well Asked Question (y)
well , for me i would first : use a main `UIScrollView` that contains both your topView and the tableView under it and that has the same width as your top `UIView` and `UITableView` and set its height to be height(tableView) + height(topView).
Second : since `UITableView` is a subClass of `UISCrollView` you can use `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate to know if the tableview is scrolled up or down.
in this cas you will have Two cases :

1) tableview is scrolled up = > you set the content offset of the main scrollView to be

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 58) animated:YES];
```

2) when the table view is scrolled down you can reset the content offset again

```
 [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't scroll the top view automatically with the table and scroll view. It all needs to look essentially like the UIView is part of the tableView and scrolls smoothly with it.