# Move a view when scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` with a `UITableView` below it:

[image]

What I would like to do is to have the view above the `UITableView` move up (out of the way) when the user starts scrolling in the table in order to have more space for the `UITableView` (and come down when you scroll down again).

I know that this is normally done with a table header view, but my problem is that my table view is inside a tab (actually it is a side-scrolling page view implemented using `TTSliddingPageviewcontroller`). So while I only have one top `UIView` there are three `UITableView`s.

Is it possible to accomplish this manually? My first thought is to put everything in a `UIScrollView`, but according to Apple's documentation one should never place a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` as this leads to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: I just wanted to ask, is all of this under a UIViewController class?

Comment: The entire scene is in a `UIViewController` which has a regular view for the top part and a container view for the bottom part. The "tab" with my `UITableViewController` is then embedded in the container view.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, your table view's delegate can receive `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

In your table view's delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static CGFloat previousOffset;
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.origin.y += previousOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    previousOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.view.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: @NobleK Do you mind sharing the code with all the checking and all?

Comment: I have added my solution as an answer.

Comment: What if these 3 tableView not the same count of rows? some very long list and some just few rows, after the tables move to the top and switch the tab to a tableview which contains just few rows. How you handle it?

Answer (score 30):

Solution for Swift (Works perfectly with bounce enabled for scroll view):

```
 var oldContentOffset = CGPointZero
 let topConstraintRange = (CGFloat(120)..<CGFloat(300))

 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let delta =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

    //we compress the top view
    if delta > 0 && topConstraint.constant > topConstraintRange.start && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        topConstraint.constant -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }

    //we expand the top view
    if delta < 0 && topConstraint.constant < topConstraintRange.end && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
        topConstraint.constant -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }

    oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
 }
```

Comment: Why is the `let topConstraintRange = (CGFloat(120)..<CGFloat(300))` from 120 to 300? Shouldn't it be 64 to 300 since the top view starts right beneath the navigation bar which is 64?

Comment: this answer is genius. I had to make a couple of changes for Swift 3, but it works great

Comment: Where do we get `topConstraint` from?

Comment: it messes the view when we scroll fast !! any solution for this problem ??

Comment: @george it's fine while scroll to top, but while scroll down not smooth like scroll top. can we make smooth scroll like top?

Comment: @HakikatSingh: You can solve this problem by using a maximum value for "delta".

Answer (score 9):

More simple and fast approach

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.origin.y =  -scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.view.frame = rect;

}
```

Comment: Its more simple  and faster than NobodyBada's answer. You don't need to add and maintain previous offset.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 & 4:

```
    var oldContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    let topConstraintRange = (CGFloat(0)..<CGFloat(140))

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let delta =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

        //we compress the top view
        if delta > 0 && yourConstraint.constant > topConstraintRange.lowerBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
            yourConstraint.constant -= delta
            scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
        }

        //we expand the top view
        if delta < 0 && yourConstraint.constant < topConstraintRange.upperBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
            yourConstraint.constant -= delta
            scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
        }
        oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
```

Comment: Design breaks when we scrolls at high speed

Comment: @Dvole yourConstraint is bind to which constraint ?

Answer (score 9):

I added some constraints to the last solution to prevent some strange behaviours in case of fast scrolling

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let delta =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

    //we compress the top view
    if delta > 0 && topConstraint.constant > topConstraintRange.lowerBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        searchHeaderTopConstraint.constant = max(topConstraintRange.lowerBound, topConstraint.constant - delta)
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }

    //we expand the top view
    if delta < 0 && topConstraint.constant < topConstraintRange.upperBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        topConstraint.constant = min(searchHeaderTopConstraint.constant - delta, topConstraintRange.upperBound)
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }
    oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Comment: where can i get that topConstraint variable?

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna you can create on in your interface builder and make an IBOutlet for it

Comment: Did the same thing. Thank you

Comment: Good solution, but a very tiny detail will make the scroll even smoother. Where is the code for `//we expand the top view`, instead of checking `delta < 0` and `scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0`, change to `<= 0` for both.

Comment: topConstraint and searchHeaderTopConstraint are top constraints for the same element?

Comment: @Exception Can you share IBOutLet for topConstraint &  searchHeaderTopConstraint Screen shots

Answer (score 3):

Someone asked for the code for my solution so I am posting it here as an answer. The credit for the idea should still go to NobodyNada.

In my `UITableViewController` I implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TableViewScrolled" object:nil userInfo:scrollUserInfo];
}
```

`scrollUserInfo` is a `NSDictionary` where I put my `UITableView` to pass it with the notification (I do this in `viewDidLoad` so I only have to do it once):

```
scrollUserInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.tableView forKey:@"scrollView"];
```

Now, in the view controller that has the view I want to move off screen while scrolling I do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScroll:) name:@"TableViewScrolled" object:nil];
```

And finally I have the method:

```
- (void)handleScroll:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"scrollView"];
    CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - currentOffset;

    if (previousOffset < currentOffset && distanceFromBottom > height) {
        if (currentOffset > viewHeight)
            currentOffset = viewHeight;
        self.topVerticalConstraint.constant += previousOffset - currentOffset;
        previousOffset = currentOffset;
    }
    else {
        if (previousOffset > currentOffset) {
            if (currentOffset < 0)
                currentOffset = 0;
            self.topVerticalConstraint.constant += previousOffset - currentOffset;
            previousOffset = currentOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

`previousOffset` is an instance variable `CGFloat previousOffset;`.
`topVerticalConstraint` is a `NSLayoutConstraint` that is set as a `IBOutlet`. It goes from the top of the view to the top of its superview and the initial value is 0.

It's not perfect. For instance, if the user scrolls very aggressively up the movement of the view can get a bit jerky. The issue is worse for large views; if the view is small enough there is no problem.

Comment: where does viewHeight come from?

Comment: The viewHeight is the height of the view above the table view in the picture shown in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To create like this animation,

[image]

```
lazy var redView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
    self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

var pageMenu: CAPSPageMenu?

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.view.addSubview(redView)

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.redView.frame.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:(self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.redView.frame.maxY)))
    pageMenu?.view.frame = rect
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

  }

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if(offset > 100){
        self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
    }else{
        self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 100 - offset)
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.redView.frame.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:(self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.redView.frame.maxY)))
    pageMenu?.view.frame = rect
}
```

> you must change **pageMenu.view** with your **collectionView/tableView**

Comment: What is CAPSPageMenu?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post in very old. I tried above solutions but neither worked for me for tried my own, hopefully it can help you. This scenario is pretty common, as apple suggested not to use TableViewController inside any ScrollView because the compiler will confused as in whom to respond becuase it will be getting two delegate call back - one from ScrollViewDelegate and another from UITableViewDelegate.

Instead we can use ScrollViewDelegate and disable the UITableViewScrolling.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat currentOffSetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat diffOffset = self.lastContentOffset - currentOffSetY;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, 400 + [self.tableView contentSize].height);

    if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y , tableView.frame.size.width,  tableView.size.height - diffOffset);
    }

    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableViewframe.origin.y, tableViewframe.size.width,  tableView.frame.size.height + diffOffset);
    }

    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffSetY;
}
```

Here lastContentOffset is CGFloat defined as property

The View Heirarchy is as follows:
ViewController --> View contains ScrollView (whose delegate method is defined above) --> Contain TableView.

By the above code we are manually increasing and decreasing the height of the table view along with the content size of ScrollView.

Remember to disable the Scrolling of TableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

Add these as your class variables:

```
private let NUMBER_OF_ROWS: Int = 256
private let ROW_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 75.0
private let MINIMUM_CONSTANT_VALUE: CGFloat = -150.0 /// This is the hidable view's height

@IBOutlet weak var hidableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! /// This is an outlet from your storyboard
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
```

This goes on your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

And then you add this as an extension for your view controller:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let delta = tableView.contentOffset.y - lastContentOffset

        let canScrollUp: Bool =
            delta < 0 &&
              hidableViewTopConstraint.constant < 0 &&
                scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0



        let canScrollDown: Bool =
            delta > 0 &&
              hidableViewTopConstraint.constant > MINIMUM_CONSTANT_VALUE &&
                tableView.contentOffset.y > 0


        if canScrollUp || canScrollDown{

            hidableViewTopConstraint.constant -= delta
            tableView.contentOffset.y -= delta

        }

        lastContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y

    }
}
```

But note that the scroll mechanism will only work when the TableView is scrolled. The top view wont collapse or expand if you scroll it.

I made an example project you can check, it is called [iOSFixedHeaderList](https://github.com/rodrigowoulddo/iOSFixedHeaderList)

Comment: hi Rodrigo. If I scroll quickly, the top bar disappears. Do you know why?

Comment: Hy, Marcel! I'm aware of this bug, but I can't tell what's wrong with the code. Sorry.

Comment: this is a good problem to solve. I found no example like that.