# Move UIView when UIScrollView scrolls up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, masonry

I am trying to accomplish something similar to this: [Move a view when scrolling in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374090/move-a-view-when-scrolling-in-uitableview) but I want to move also one of the views in the background (not all of them). This is what I've done so far (I use Masonry for the autoLayout):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    //There is an array of views, which I want to move when scrolling

    for (UIView *view in self.movedViews) {


        CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    //Here I get the default Y origin of the view, so I can move them equally

        originY = view.frame.origin.y;
        CGFloat diff = (scrollView.contentInset.top)-originY;

        [view mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.mas_equalTo(view.superview.mas_top).with.offset((-offset)-diff);
        }];
    }

}
```

The problem is I can't get `view.frame.origin.y` without changing it later with `mas_updateConstraints`. Also I want to make so the views move only when scrolling upwards. I am open to any different solutions. Thank you guys!

Comment: what do u mean by cant get view.frame.origin.y?

Comment: what is movedViews, and how r u setting it?

Comment: movedViews is the array of views I want to move(I set them in the init method of the delegate), and view.frame.origin.y is needed in the last line, so I can move every view equally and don't set the same constraint for every one of them

Comment: what do u mean by cant get view.frame.origin.y?

Comment: I mean I get the the view.frame.origin.y, but I want to save the initial value and keep it unchanged in this variable, because the mas_updateConstraints method is changing the view.frame.origin.y. I want the originY to keep its initial value.