# Pushing up Collection Header view when scrolling in Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am rebuilding Instagram and currently work on the features of my profile.

As in instagram, i am having a header view pinned to the top and, unlike Instagram, a tableview underneath (instead of a collection View).

I want that when the user scrolls down in the tableview, the header gets pushed up and the tableview takes up to the full screen.

I have tried everything I ´ve found on stack overflow but not seem to accomplish my goals.

I tried the solution from this post
[Move a view when scrolling in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374090/move-a-view-when-scrolling-in-uitableview?noredirect=1&lq=1)

With the code

```
  var oldContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
let topConstraintRange = (CGFloat(64)..<CGFloat(250))

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let delta =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

    //we compress the top view
    if delta > 0 && collectionView.frame.size.height > topConstraintRange.lowerBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        collectionView.frame.size.height -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }

    //we expand the top view
    if delta < 0 && collectionView.frame.size.height < topConstraintRange.upperBound && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
        collectionView.frame.size.height -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }
    oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

I only accomplish that when a user scrolls the tableview, the header gets pushed up, but the tableview remains the same size.

[image: This is before scrolling]

[image: The tableview remains the same size, the header gets pushed up.]

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this by putting the tableview into a scrollview instead of using a header for the stuff above the tableview. This is not good practice but it works.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick answer. I am trying to have the best code practice and I got told that the way I do it is the one preferable. Still don't know how to change the tableview depending on the scroll.

Comment: Did you try using scrollviewdidscroll?

Comment: yes, please look at my code what i did implement