# Is it possible fix the position of first row on UITableController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have used a `UITableViewController`sub class to display a list of data. I finished every thing in the project, but the client needs the top row of the table to stay on top and not scroll with the rest of the content. I know this could easily be achieved using a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController` but would like to avoid this. I'm here for a final attempt to see if there is any way to fix some rows in a table view.

Please note that there are 4 different `UITableViewController`'s in my project and they all have some complex logic in their table view delegate methods. This means a lot of work if I need to change all the `UITableViewController`s into `UIViewController`s.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider to add that cell as a header for first section of your table view?

Comment: you can create view and add it to your section header if your table has only 1 section.

Comment: Yes, i have only one section in table view..so let me try this option

Comment: @Szu and Chinttu 'RoxeN' Ramani, i'v search bar on all the tables after creating header what will be the position of search bar on top or under section header?

Comment: Have you added the search bar as table header

Comment: you just need to create customview and return in `viewForHeaderInSection` method. you can add anything in it.another option is you can also add searchbar in `table.tableHeaderView = yoursearchbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. More common practice is to use property of the `UITableView`

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
   ```
2. Second way to place your table view as child view and add another subview

   - `UIView`

     - HEADER `UIView`
     - `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to implement method (declared in `UITableViewDelegate`):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.yourHeaderTopView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the custom tableheaderview. For more refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 cells
use first as static and fill up the information as u want.
set the Reuse modifier of the second and call that second cell in the 
cellAtRowForIndexPath method to use that second cell continuously