# Resizing UITableview height programmatically

Tags: ios, scrollview

I have scrollview which has four labels and under each label there is tableview, i want to adjust tableview according to data and move label after tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not understanding your question wrong, you can use `UITableView` with headers implementations.

Here's the help,

[Customize UITableView header section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)