# Swipe to delete cell causes tableViewHeader to move with cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have encountered a strange bug with my `tableViewHeader` on my `UITableView` in iOS 8. When swiping on a cell to reveal the delete button (standard iOS swipe-to-delete), it moves the `tableViewHeader` along with the cell that is being swiped. As I swipe the cell, the header moves in the same way that the cell being swiped does. No other cells in the table view are moved, only the header and whatever cell is being swiped. I have tested this on iOS 7 haven't encountered the problem. To me, this seems like a bug with `tableViewHeader` in iOS 8, being that it only occurs in this version and seems like something that should never occur. I see no reason for the header to ever be included in swipe-to-delete.

Below is just a mockup. Swipe-to-delete within the app is default iOS, nothing custom.

[image: Below is just a mockup. Swipe-to-delete within the app is default iOS, nothing custom.]

Comment: send your issue in detail @Ferris

Comment: I am also encountering this problem and I'm surprised no one else has this issue.

How are you creating the header?

I created it via the prototype cells and reusing them as headers. I haven't tried the default header or creating a new one from scratch (code) yet though.

Comment: I would also like to note that any swipe is also causing not just it's own section header to shift together with it, but all other section headers as well. Is it the same with your side too?

Comment: Fixed the issue. If you are using a UITableViewCell as the header for the table, wrap it in a UIView. See my answer bellow. @CyberMew

Comment: I would recommend the approach of wrapping the header cell in a UIView as @ferris suggested. I tried the approach below with referencing cell.contentView but some of the buttons on my cell would not display.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Building on ferris's answer, I found the easiest way when using a UITableViewCell as a section header is to return the contentView of the cell in viewForHeaderInSection.  The code is as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  cell : cellSectionHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeader") as cellSectionHeader
    return cell.contentView
    //cellSectionHeader is my subclassed UITableViewCell
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  Just adding ".contentView" to the returned cell was all I needed.

Comment: When I add .contentView I just get blank space instead of the correct headers

Comment: @Carlos I had the same happen when I was using a standard 'basic' cell. Changing it to a custom worked.

Comment: @SimonB yeah I ended up doing this with a separate xib file. Works.

Comment: I believe the background color of a head is lost after this.

Comment: It solved the problem of swiping of header but my header had a button, which is now unresponsive

Answer (score 25):

This was caused because I was using a UITableViewCell as the header for the table. To solve the swiping issue, instead of using `tableView.tableHeaderView = cell`, I use the following:

```
UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[cellView addSubview:cell];
tableView.tableHeaderView = cellView
```

I don't know why this solves the problem, especially being that it worked on iOS 7, but it seems to solve the problem.

Make sure to add all view to the cells view, as supposed to the cells contentView, otherwise the buttons will not be responsive.

Works:

`[cell addSubview:view];` or `[self addSubview:view];`

Doesn't work:

`[cell.contentView addSubview:view]` or `[self.contentView addSubview:view]`

Comment: I just tried it and it works mostly fine. However I have a button in the header cell and it isn't responding anymore to touches. It is as if userInteractionEnabled is set to NO, even though I made sure all of it is YES.

Comment: Had the same problem. I found that if objects are added to the cells contentView then they are not responsive. If you add them to the cells view they work fine. ex: `[cell addSubview:view];` or in a custom cell: `[self addSubview:view];` @CyberMew

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of adding the cell to UIView directly I added the cell.contentView instead. This way nothing else changes - you still make your cell in the storyboard. Everything works fine now. Even my old issue of tapping the header and resulted in the first row being selected is now fixed :). In my case I originally hacked the master split view to be a wider width so as an extra step I now had to also set the cell.contentView's frame and bounds (and the constraints in the storyboard of course) to make it look correctly on iOS7 and iOS8. Thank you for pointing me in the right way! :)

Comment: This was the code I used (in viewForHeaderInSection):
 `UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.contentView.bounds];

 [cellView addSubview:headerView.contentView]; // headerView is the cell from dequeue
 return cellView;`

Comment: Strangely enough, nobody seemed to say (s)he reported the bug to Apple. To me, this is a bug, and this is still in iOS 9 (Beta 2, Xcode 7 Beta 3 crashes on me....):  http://www.openradar.me/21765862

Comment: Wrapping it in UIView will change a header size.

Answer (score 9):

The way to avoid the headers moving with the cells is to return the contentView of the cell in viewForHeaderInSection. If you have a subclassed UITableViewCell named SectionHeaderTableViewCell, this is the correct code:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    SectionHeaderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SectionHeader"];
    //Do stuff to configure your cell
    return cell.contentView; 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have a subclassed custom cell for my header and returned the contentView of that cell implementation. Swiping to delete below rows in the section does not slide the header cell,

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.0** Tested solution. As mentioned in the first example for Objective-C; the key point is returning **cell.contentView** instead of **cell** So new format syntax is as below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    // HeaderCell is the name of custom row designed in Storyboard->tableview->cell prototype
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell")

    cell.songLabel.text = "Your Section Name"
    return cell.contentView
}
```

Comment: In my cell I added all custom components(like labels) programmatically, using "self.addSubview(customComponent)". With this proposed solution I also had to change that to "self.contentView.addSubview(customComponent)".

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this method and give proper conditions for checking the swipe.If this method get called for header view.

1.tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: 2.tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath: 3.tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve any problems. `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` never gets called. I believe this is intended for grouped tables. As for `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`, it only gets called once for the cell that is being swiped. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

One problem not mentioned with the .contentView method is that if your table view cell makes use of layoutSubviews, you may not get the behavior you want-- because layoutSubviews will not get called. I ended up making an entirely separate UIView subclass that supports both normal cell operation and header operation, and creating a bare minimum UITableView cell class that uses that.

Answer (score -1):

Victor's issue of losing background color, is solved by below addition to Brad's answer:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

To:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```