# uitableview header view issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a tableview and i have 2 sections. in second section i need a header . so i did this like below.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 1 {
        return 40
    }
    return 0
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 1 {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("audiocellheader")! as UITableViewCell

        return header
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I have a problem when i reload the section.Header get disappeared.if i do tableview.reload its works fine. what will be the issue?. Also i have an issue when i delete the item in the cell. image is given below.
[image]

header get moves as same as edited row.

Comment: Are you setting heightforheader properly?

Comment: Don't you want to use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier`?

Comment: @kiran it s not about the height. view is disappeared when i reload the section when i add an entry or delete.

Comment: @Tim let me check with dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier

Comment: @TimVermeulen I am getting this error UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose What? Are you trying to set the background color of a header/footer somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link from here [Swipe to delete cell causes tableViewHeader to move with cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009722/swipe-to-delete-cell-causes-tableviewheader-to-move-with-cell)  got the answer.

instead of cell return cell.contentview.both issue resolved

```
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
         if section == 1 {
               let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("audiocellheader")! as UITableViewCell
               return header.contentView
        }   
        else {
             return nil
        }
      }
```