# When using a UIView with cell content as a header for viewForHeaderInSection, how to restrict it's width to the tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

My original problem was when using a cell in viewForHeaderInSection, how to keep the header from moving when swiping to delete a cell in it's section.

I was able to solve that problem with accepted solution at
[Swipe to delete cell causes tableViewHeader to move with cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009722/swipe-to-delete-cell-causes-tableviewheader-to-move-with-cell).

But now the the elements of the header are no longer properly constrained to the width of the UITableview and go off the screen

My code is below:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

MyHeaderCell *myHeaderCell = (MyHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
    UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        UILabel *myHeaderLabel = (UILabel *)[myHeaderCell viewWithTag:2020];
        [myHeaderLabel setText:[self setMyHeaderLabel]];
        [myHeaderCell initHeaderShowAndSortSelects];
        myHeaderCell.parentTableViewController = self;
        myHeaderCell.contentView.backgroundColor = myHeaderCell.backgroundColor;
        [cellView addSubview:myHeaderCell];
        cellView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        return cellView;
}
```

MyHeaderCell is a subclass of UITableCell with IBOutlets that are connected to the elements of the header on the storyboard.

When I was returning myHeaderCell directly, the header was properly constrained with auto layout constraints all working, BUT would swipe left along with a cell in the table I wanted to delete.

It's tantilizingly close to working perfectly: touch elements responding/modifying tableView cells, header static, not scrolling with tableview, no longer swiping left, but with a width that is too big.

Comment: Did you try to add the `autoresizingMask` to `myHeaderCell` as you're adding it as subview. `myHeaderCell. autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` ?

Comment: @vhristoskov, well that definitely had an impact which is more than I can say for the other things I've tried.  Now the header is much wider than it was before, but I can begin working with this to constrain it, just gotta figure out which values will produce the right results.

Comment: You also need to set myHeaderCell.frame = cellView.bounds along with setting the resizing mask.  That sets the initial size; the autoresizingMask indicates how myHeaderCell will resize when the table view changes the cellView frame later on.

Comment: @CarlLindberg  thanks and right on, you must've been writing this at the same time I posted my imperfect answer.  I did exactly that but when I began trying different values I thought it would have been -80.0f and the contraints were wider not narrower.  I eventually settled on +80.0f, but my answer is flawed as this hardcoding probably won't hold up for all screen sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vhristoskov okay your suggestion helped me to understand the purpose of UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and the general method of usage of an autoresizingMask (on the subview and for stretching/contstraining bottom, right, left margins) AND led to a solution that works but that isn't ideal.

I've changed my code to the following:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect f = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, f.size.width+80.0f, f.size.height)];//sets a base for the cell/superview  I don't like it because it's just a number I played around with not a formula
UILabel *myHeaderLabel = (UILabel *)[myHeaderCell viewWithTag:2020];
    [myHeaderLabel setText:[self setMyHeaderLabel]];
    [myHeaderCell initHeaderShowAndSortSelects];
    myHeaderCell.parentTableViewController = self;
    myHeaderCell.contentView.backgroundColor = myHeaderCell.backgroundColor;
    [cellView addSubview:myHeaderCell];
    myHeaderCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; //autoresizingMask needs to be applied to the subview!

    return cellView;
}
```

I have marked my own answer as the solution because it works with the 80.0f value tacked on to the end of the cellView's derived width, but to do it right IT SHOULD BE A FORMULA (for future readers).

If anyone(@vhristoskov) wants to talk about the geometry involved so as to derive an ideal solution have at it.  As is not sure how this will look on different screen sizes.

It probably requires the constraints of the header be made explicit so as to calculate the value that the hard-coded 80.0f represents.

Comment: The table view will reset the frame width on whatever view you give it, so that should not matter.  However, given your resizing mask, that value *will* affect what happens to myHeaderCell (the subview) when the outer view gets resized.   So, if myHeaderCell's arbitrary width set in the xib happens to be 80 points wider than your current screen, the above will result in the subview always being the width of the screen / table view, which is what you want.

Comment: To make it more generic, make myHeaderCell and cellView have the same width (doesn't matter the actual value as it will be reset) -- i.e. use myHeaderCell.frame.size.width instead of f.size.with+80 .  That way the two views start out as the same width, and as cellView gets resized, myHeaderCell gets sized to match due to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth (and the lack of FlexibleLeftMargin / FlexibleRightMargin).

Comment: @CarlLindberg The explanation makes perfect sense and the results are all good, I accept this answer and think it makes a nice bookend to the swipe left header problem that I see gets a lot of traffic here.