# The application is Crashing on UItableCellSection long press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    simpleCell = [self.dashboardListView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (simpleCell == nil) {

        simpleCell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        simpleCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    ///tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped)];
    ///[simpleCell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:simpleCell.frame];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [simpleCell.contentView addSubview:button];

    NSDictionary *dict = [cellnames objectAtIndex:section];

    simpleCell.cellName.text = (NSString *)[dict valueForKey:@"cellname"];
    simpleCell.count.text = [[countArray objectAtIndex:section]stringValue];


    return simpleCell;

}
```

Above code is working fine.

Problem is :- **It is crashing when I long press the simpleCell on the tableView.**

I am getting crash log as

> *** -[SimpleTableCell hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f86dc0b2420`

any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the long press gesture recogniser assigned? Is it inside the cell? Could you post some code of that?

Comment: Good morning Gary Riches, The long press gesture recognizer is not assigned at all.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, UIButton inside a table view cell crashes on long press.  Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. In my case creating UIView for the header view instead of using UITableViewCell helped.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try

`cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` 
had the same issue. disabling userInteraction resolved for me .

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I solved it using UIView *objView in place of using CustomTableCell.

Try this will help.