# App crashes when I long press on UITableView Custom Header Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have a simple `UITableViewController` with a set of data, employee first name and last name. I have created a custom header prototype cell with just one Label to set the header title.

However the issue is that, when ever user "Long Press" on the header cell on the table, the App Crashes.

In the attached screen shot, Header0, Header1, Header3, Header4 when "Long Press"ed, the app crashes. 
However, the header section marked in the red oval is a simple UIView for header but without any Label or any control. The strange thing is if the user "Long Press" this empty header, the app won't crash.

The code for header view

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if ( section == 2 ){
            var emptyView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 50))
            return emptyView
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! UITableViewCell

        let c = cell as! HeaderTableViewCell
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        c.headerTextLabel.text = "Header" + toString(section)
        return c.contentView
    }
```

Wondering what is happening. I have recently updated Xcode to 6.3 which has Swift 1.2. How to fix this issue?

Any help is much appreciated

Within the [image: Sample UITableView with Custom Header cell]

Comment: Have you implemented any gesture for header?

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace of the crash.

Comment: No gestures have been implemented. Its just a simple table view controller.

Comment: @JAL: No trace either.. Its just empty with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x19)

Comment: When you get the crash in lldb type `bt all` and post the result.

Comment: 015-06-11 11:29:14.442 TableAddingNewRecord[3017:82638] -[_UITableViewCellSeparatorView _gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd215043610
2015-06-11 11:29:14.447 TableAddingNewRecord[3017:82638] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITableViewCellSeparatorView _gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd215043610'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c6ac65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

Comment: 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a7d5bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c720ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108bc813c ___forwarding___ + 988
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108bc7cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   UIKit                               0x00000001098bb784 -[UIGestureRecognizer _shouldBegin] + 1227
 6   UIKit                               0x00000001098b74b6 -[UIGestureRecognizer setState:] + 256

Comment: 14  UIKit                               0x0000000109509900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
 15  TableAddingNewRecord                0x0000000108a38aa7 main + 135
 16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010af2d145 start + 1
 17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Any update from anyone?? Any solution for this kind of scenario.??

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by removing gestures on the content view (c.contentView) of cell.

```
 if let recognizers = c.contentView.gestureRecognizers
  {
  for recognizer in recognizers {
  c.contentView.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31877323/67667 i.e. disable user interactions for the header cell:
`c.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false`