# What is the name of the font and the colour used for UITableView cell headers?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to replicate the default font, colour and size used for cell headers.
Does anybody know exactly what they are? Cheers!

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the cell style is **grouped**, not the default **plain** style.

Comment: Use full this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts used are **SFUI** Text Regular **13 pts** with color **R:0.43 G:0.43 B:0.45 A:1**