# Customize header in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to customize header in section in UITableView. I couldn't find to do it in storyboard so I started adding UIView and UILabel.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5,2, tableView.frame.size.width - 5, 30))
    headerLabel.text = sectionTitle  (this is a variable)
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 18)
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
```

It makes a view like below:
[image]

I am looking for a way to locate UILabel vertically and horizontally center of the view. How would I do that? Would it always change whenever I change the font and size?

Also, would there by anyway I can do this in storyboard? It is really hard to make header programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section you should implement that method and create a custom view in storyboard. In that method, load your custom view and return it.

Comment: Perfect demo, but if I want to fix position view header when scroll up, is it possible?

Answer (score 28):

You can drag a UIView on your UITableView in your storyboard. The view will be added as your UITableView Header automatically. See the view hierarchy in the picture below.

Next create a UILabel in your header view and set the auto layout constraints:

- Center vertically in superview
- Center horizontally in superview

You will end up with something like this:

[image: Storyboard View]

**EDIT:**

Editing my answer in order to reply to your comment.
If you want to have a custom header view for every section you can override `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` like you are already doing.

Then create a `@IBOutlet UIView *headerView;` which you will return in the delegate method mentioned above. 
Go to your storyboard and drag a UIView from the object palette to the top bar of your `UIViewController/UITableViewController` (see the attached image).

Next connect your outlet to the created `UIView`. You can design your view in storyboard afterwards and add an `IBOutlet` for your `UILabel` in order to update its text content for every section header view you create.

[image: Section Header View in storyboard]

Comment: Oh shoot.. I should have been more clear. I meant adding custom header view for each section in UITableView. Your way seems like to create only one view in tableView. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Perfect demo, but if I want to fix position view header when scroll up, is it possible?

Comment: @LeangSocheat If you want to have a fixed header which will not scroll you should go with the first approach I mentioned. A table header view is always fixed and will not scroll when the tableview is scrolled in contrast to section header views which scroll with the respective section of the tableview.

Comment: yes I did with your first approach, but that view header still scroll. does I lack of any property ?

Comment: The UILabel only takes the last string. I.E. i have "First Title", "Second Title", "Third Title". The only shows, "Third Title" and others sections appears empty. Do you know why ? ( i'm following your example here )

Answer (score 1):

Just create a custom view and provide layout constraints in your preferred way.

For example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        UIView *container = [UIView new];
        UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [container addSubview:label];
        [container addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(20)-[label]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil  views:@{@"label" : label }]];
        [container addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(15)-[label]-(3)-|" options:0 metrics:nil   views:@{@"label" : label}]];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %ld", section];
        return container;   
    }
```

In addition you can put this code in a separate class and you could layout the view in a XIB.

Swift:

```
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, 
                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                      toItem: container, attribute: .CenterX, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
container.addConstraint(xConstraint);

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, 
                                   relatedBy: .Equal, 
                                   toItem: container, attribute: .CenterY, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
container.addConstraint(yConstraint);

let hConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, 
                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                      toItem: container,attribute: .Height, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
container.addConstraint(hConstraint);

let wConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, 
                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                      toItem: container, attribute: .Width, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
container.addConstraint(wConstraint);
```

Comment: You should add a swift version of your code since the OP is using Swift as you can see from his question above.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot table header in storyboard, however if need customization you need to  create a custom class and its corresponding xib file