# I want to add a sort and filter button on top of tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, viewcontroller

[image: This is from myntra app u can check it for reference i want implement exactly like this .]

I want to implement Something like this two views for Sort and Refine on top of table view.

is there something called table header or something similar where i can add this .

this screenshot is from myntra app u can check that for reference.

Comment: just do some basic research before asking the question. There are  lot of tutorials and other threads based on this topic. Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35009150/3578310

Answer (score 3):

Use a `UIViewController` with a container `UIView` on top and a `UITableView` in bottom

Something like in the screenshot

[image]

Grey part is the `UITableViewController`
Upper part is a `UIStackView` with 3 buttons in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let header = UIView(frame:  CGRect(0,0,view.frame.width,30))     
  return header

}
```

create a view with two buttons Sort and Filter and return in above function also dont forget to return height in below func

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

this will give you sticky header like Myntra app

OR return view in `tableView.tableHeaderView = yourview` but this will not stick and get scrolled along the scroll

Comment: how to design the view , do i have to design it programatically

Comment: any option from nib or programmatically above i have made edit with programamtically

Comment: can i make custom tableview cell.

Comment: add it as a header

Comment: Y UITableViewCell make UIView