# adding some margin below section header text of a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have styled the header text:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

    cell!.titleLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section].objects[indexPath.row].name
    cell!.datetimeLabel!.text = "on " + sections[indexPath.section].objects[indexPath.row].date

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 100
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].heading // Open Events
}
```

And I would like to add some margin / padding below it before the section of the table cells start. I have added some margin / padding top with `heightForHeaderInSection`. Any way to add some top / bottom margin / padding?

[image]

Comment: can you not make the headers height even larger, and move the "open events" label up?

Comment: make the heightForHeaderInSection to 120 and try.

Comment: @Fonix "open events" is not a label, but section header set in function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)` as I just added in the code

Comment: @Signare making it to 120 will just increase the top spacing more, without any bottom spacing

Comment: create a label and add it to cell. so you can set the top spacing of that label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`titleForHeaderInSection` method will have the default section header frame. You can use `viewForHeaderInSection` method to customize it. Try this code :

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerFrame = tableView.frame

    let title = UILabel()
    title.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 10, headerFrame.size.width-20, 20) //width equals to parent view with 10 left and right margin
    title.font = title.font.fontWithSize(14)
    title.text = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section) //This will take title of section from 'titleForHeaderInSection' method or you can write directly
    title.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerFrame.size.width, headerFrame.size.height))
    headerView.addSubview(title)

    return headerView
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, yes it works now with a bit of tweak https://gist.github.com/sayanee/a164f7f22423c17494e6. I'm wondering though if the `CGRectMake`'s 3rd argument for width can be dynamic to take the parent width.

Comment: here's a screenshot if you wanna update https://www.dropbox.com/s/ook1ymq6jglsa0o/Screenshot%202016-02-12%2013.59.13.png?dl=0

Comment: you mean,you want title lable's height as the same of headerView height?

Comment: oops, I meant the label's width to be the same as the section header's width (not height)

Comment: ah..sorry. I meant width actually. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you :) It's all good now! If you want, you can use the dropbox link for the image and the gist for the update code.

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

use `viewForHeaderInSection:` and return a view with a label with the correct spacing below it instead of using the default header in `titleForHeaderInSection`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15611529/1219956) for an example