# Too long text for titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So what my problem is that my text above my section is too long and gets cut off.

[image: example]

Any way to solve this like making it two rows long?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Respond to the delegate `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection `  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:  Return a taller view with a multiline label subview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize UITableView header section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the `heightForHeaderInSection` and customize `viewForHeaderInSection`. You can either fix all header heights at a value big enough for all lines, or calculate the required height for the specific header (as below).

```
let headerFont:UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14);
let headerTexts = ["one line", "two line test123 sadfjklsadf asdjfklasjdflk asdfjklasdjfl asdfjklsadf"];

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return heightOfHeaderText(headerTexts[section]);
}

func heightOfHeaderText(text:String) -> CGFloat{
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(
        CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 999),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : headerFont],
        context: nil).size.height;


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: section)));
    headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
    headerLabel.font = headerFont;
    headerLabel.text = headerTexts[section];

    return headerLabel;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom view with a label in it. And use viewForHeaderInSection delegate method to assign text to that label and return this view.

EDIT:

See this link
[Customize UITableView header section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more information what to do?