# How to customize UIView of sections in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I want to set the style my sections in a UITableView like `viewForFooterInSection` or `viewForHeaderInSection`.

I only can set the title using `titleForHeaderInSection` and height using `heightForHeaderInSection` but I want to set the baground color, font-size, font-color, etc...

It's posible do that?

Comment: Yes, create UIView and implement the `viewForHeaderInSection` and then return your view.

Comment: You can do whatever you want to your views for the section headers and footers. Please clarify what trouble you are having. Your questions isn't very clear.

Comment: Duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this delegate method whic provide by apple.

```
//for header 
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //give size for veiw, background color, add label anything here



    return myview;
}


//for footer

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //give size for veiw, background color, add label anything here



    return myview;
}
```